# Duda sobre rutas y middlewares laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

tengo una duda sobre las rutas en laravel, estuve investigando como crear y registrar un nuevo archivo de rutas, vi que al registrarlo en el archivo `RouteServiceProvider.php` hay que indicar que middlewares quieres que se apliquen y el namespace de donde estarán los controladores que interactuaran con esta ruta, por ejemplo el del archivo web.php:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

mi duda es la siguiente: Si tengo rutas registradas en el archivo web.php, y los controladores que interactúan en este archivo de rutas están en carpetas en `App\Http\Controllers\X_carpeta\controlador.php`, se aplican los middleware del sistema de rutas "web"? o es necesario ponerlos de forma manual?. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ese caso se aplicará a todas las rutas que están en el archivo web.php el middleware 'web'.

Te coloco un ejemplo de como yo coloco el middleware auth en un archivo de rutas admin.php

```
 Route::prefix('admin')
        ->middleware('web','auth')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
```

En este caso, todas las rutas que está en el archivo admin.php tienen los middleware 'web'y 'auth'

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, entonces el namespace, ¿para qué sirve?. Pensaba que los middleware especificados se aplicarían a los controladores dentro del namespace

Comment: Esta propiedad se usa para prefijar automáticamente las declaraciones de ruta del controlador y la generación de URL de ruta del controlador en versiones anteriores de Laravel 8. 
Te dejo el link de la documentación oficial de Laravel para que tengas un poco mas de información.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing